# Copy and paste url parts in forms

Tags: copy-paste

How can I get a part of a string from the specific starting position to end. Like for example I want to copy v=mQUr2RkjykU from the given url:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQUr2RkjykU

If url is writen into form, how can i copy and paste that part. 
And write it mysite.com/watch?xxxxxxxxxxx  in a link thats generated.

```
<input id="Form" name="Form" type="text" /><input id="Button" type="button" value="" />
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

In your case , you can check the position of '?' in your URL>>

```
$oldUrl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQUr2RkjykU';    
$newUrl = substr($oldUrl, 1, strpos($oldUrl, '?')-1);
```

$newUrl would be your answer,

anyway , try to search more before asking question here :)